# References for $\mathbb Q_p^\times/(\mathbb Q_p^\times)^2$

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

where can i find a proof that shows $\mathbb Q_p^\times/(\mathbb Q_p^\times)^2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} $?
Thank you for the answers !

Comment: If $p=2$, it isn't.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/551582/254075) answer.

Comment: @sharding4 sorry the question was not completely clear , in the case p=2 i can prove it but in the general case no, you reference is very good thank you

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2202988/square-classes-p-adic-numbers-isomorphism

Comment: Is this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551562/properties-of-squares-in-mathbb-q-p?rq=1 answer you?