# Order of $\mathbb{Q}_{p}^{\times }/ (\mathbb{Q}_{p}^{\times })^{2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory, quotient-group

> Let $p\neq 2$ be a prime. An element $x\in\mathbb{Q}_{p}$
> is a square if and only if it can be written as $x=p^{2n}y^{2}$ with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $y\in\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{\times }$ a $p$-adic unit. The quotient $\mathbb{Q}_{p}^{\times }/(\mathbb{Q}_{p}^{\times })^{2}$ has order $4$. If $c\in\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{\times }$ is any element whose reduction modulo $p$ is not a quadratic residue, then the set $\{ 1,p,c,cp\}$ is a complete set of coset representative.

I have some difficult to prove the second part. Maybe I din't understhood well the structure of the quotient, because I think it is the set of the class of squares, but I don't see how this can help to determine the order and the coset representatives. I have seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551562/properties-of-squares-in-mathbb-q-p) that $\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{\times }/(\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{\times })^{2}$ has oder $2$, but I don't see why this with the isomorphism $\mathbb{Q}_{p}\cong \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ gives the answer.

Comment: See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551562/properties-of-squares-in-mathbb-q-p), why the quotient is $\Bbb Z/2\times \Bbb Z/2$, so has order $4$. See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2760987/references-for-mathbb-q-p-times-mathbb-q-p-times2?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: I see that question, but I didn't understhood how to prove this. In the end it says that $\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{\times }/(\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{\times })^{2}$ has order 2, and I don't sse why this is enough

Comment: Why? Because we have an isomorphism of groups $\mathbb{Q}_p^* = \langle p \rangle \cdot \mathbb{Z}_p^* \cong \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_p^*$.

Comment: I see this. What I don't see is how the fact that $\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{\times }/(\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{\times })^{2}$ has order $2$ together with the isomorphism of $\mathbb{Q}_{p}^{\times }$ gives that $\mathbb{Q}_{p}^{\times }/(\mathbb{Q}_{p}^{\times })^{2}$ has order $4$.

Comment: You have two factors in $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z_p^*$. Taking quotients, the first factor becomes $\Bbb Z/2$, and the second one becomes $\Bbb F_p^*/(\Bbb F_p^*)^2\cong \Bbb Z/2$. So we obtain order $4$.

Comment: Can you write explicitly the quotient? Maybe my confusion is due to the fact the we have the quotient of product

Comment: Since $\Bbb Q_p^{\times}=\langle p\rangle \times \Bbb Z_p^{\times}$, we have $$\Bbb Q_p^{\times}/(\Bbb Q_p^{\times})^2\cong \langle p\rangle / \langle p^2\rangle \times \Bbb Z_p^{\times}/(\Bbb Z_p^{\times})^2$$

Comment: Hence, for the quotient $⟨p⟩/⟨ p^{2}⟩$ we have only two equivalence classes, $[1]$ and $[p]$. Right?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sorry for bothering you, I would like to ask a last question. When in the answer he says "If $p \neq 2$, look at the canonical homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_p^* \to \mathbb{F}_p^*$. It is surjective, and by what you have said it pulls back ${\mathbb{F}_p^*}^2$ to ${\mathbb{Z}_p^*}^2$. In other words, it induces an isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_p^* / {\mathbb{Z}_p^*}^2 \cong \mathbb{F}_p^* / {\mathbb{F}_p^*}^2$", why we have an isomorphism in the quotient if the canonical homomorphism is only surjective?