# Isomorphism between quotient of p adic units and quotient of $\mathbb{F}_{p}^{\times }$

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory, group-homomorphism

I have some problems to understand why

$$\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{* }/(\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{* })^{2}\cong \mathbb{F}_{p}^{* }/(\mathbb{F}_{p}^{* })^{2}$$

I have seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551562/properties-of-squares-in-mathbb-q-p) that there is this induced isomorphism by the fact that the canonical homomorphism
$$\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{\times }\rightarrow\mathbb{F}_{p}^{\times }$$
pulls back
$(\mathbb{F}_{p}^{\times })^{2}$
to
$(\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{\times })^{2}$,
but I can't see why this is enough. Maybe I am missing some basic property. The canonical homomorphsim is only surjective and the kernel is $1+p\mathbb{Z}_{p}$, hence I don't understand why in the quotient became an isomorphism.
I think that in the quotient I have only two classes, because if $x\in\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*}$ isn't a square, then the coset consist of all elements who's not a square. This is the same in $\mathbb{F}_{p}^{*}$ (For example I considered $\mathbb{F}_{5}^{*}$ and this works). But I'm not completely sure.

Comment: It suffices to show that $1+p\mathbb Z_p$ is contained in $(\mathbb Z_p^*)^2$.

Comment: @SeanEberhard this follows from the fact that if $x\in 1+p \mathbb{Z}_{p}$ then its reduction modulo $p\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is $1$ which is clearly a square. Right?

Comment: No, that doesn't prove anything. One has to show that every element of $1 + p\mathbb Z_p$ is a square. Hint: use the Taylor expansion of $(1 + x)^{1/2}$ and assume $p \ne 2$. (The claim is not true for $p=2$.)

Comment: $(1+x)^{1/2}=1+\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}\frac{-1}{2}\frac{1}{2!}x^{2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{-1}{2}\frac{-3}{2}\frac{1}{3!}x^{3}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{-1}{2}\frac{-3}{2}\frac{-5}{2}\frac{1}{4!}x^{4}+...$. Now, if $p\neq 2$, since $x\in p\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ then $v_{p}(x)\geq 1$. In particular, at the denominators we have always $2$ which not divides $p$ and then $v_{p}$ increasing and the expansion converges. If $p=2$ we need $v_{p}(x)\geq 3$ because otherwise the p adic valuation is negative or always $2$. Is it right?

Comment: Alternatively, Hensel's Lemma.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg In which way? What I wrote is wrong?

Comment: What you wrote works, which is why I said "alternatively". And "in what way", well to show that the equation $x^2=a$ has a solution in $\mathbb Z_p$ for $a \equiv 1$ mod $p$ and $p$ odd.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4814652/order-of-mathbbq-p-times-mathbbq-p-times-2?noredirect=1&lq=1), for context.