# Are $\Bbb R^\times$ and $\Bbb Q_p^\times$ isomorphic as groups?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, real-numbers, p-adic-number-theory

The question is:

> Is the multiplicative group of $\Bbb R$ isomorphic (as a group) to the multiplicative group of $\Bbb Q_p$?

The question is motivated by the observation that the additive group of $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb Q_p$ are isomorphic (which can be seen from a cardinality argument and both being $\Bbb Q$ vector spaces) and that $\Bbb C_p$ and $\Bbb C$ are isomorphic as fields (apparently a difficult result from class field theory).

Since such an isomorphism need not have any compatibility with addition, so it seems to me that arguments that use sub-rings or ideals are not helpful. On the other hand such an isomorphism would induce representations of $GL(n,\Bbb Q_p)$ to $\Bbb R$ (by composing with the determinant), so maybe a representation theory argument might be the way to go.

Comment: $\Bbb C_p$ and $\Bbb C$ are isomorphic as fields because they are uncountable, of characteristic $0$ and algebraically closed — this has nothing to do with class field theory.

Comment: The subgroup of squares in $\Bbb Q_p^{\times}$ has never index $2$ in $\Bbb Q_p^{\times}$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2202988/square-classes-p-adic-numbers-isomorphism), so that the answer to your question is "no".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not in general: $\Bbb Q_p^\times$ has $p-1$ torsion elements for odd $p$
while $\Bbb R^\times$ has two. So for $p\notin\{2,3\}$ they are non-isomorphic.

When $p\in\{2,3\}$ one has to work harder. The group of squares
in $\Bbb R^\times$ has index two. This is never the case for $\Bbb Q_p^\times$.

Comment: An even slicker argument: every real number is a cube, but $p$ is not a cube in $\Bbb Q_p$.

Comment: What would an example of an element with torsion $p-1$ look like?

Comment: @s.harp The Teichmuller lift of a primitive root modulo $p$.

Comment: Quick, @s.harp, pull out your pencil and prove to yourself that there is a square root of $-1$ in $\Bbb Q_5$, in other words, a primitive fourth root of unity.